# Is there a way to perform multiple checks in Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, statistics

I'm looking to check values over a range of multiple cells altering the data in my current cell dependant on the result. My below method works but poorly. My goal is a setup with multiple checks (one for each criteria) or one function that checks each criteria.

The below image shows the current setup that I've done in each cell.
In column AT I have the following formula:

```
=IFERROR(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Zero Ticket Booking",AS126)),"Zero Ticket Booking",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Refunded Booking",AS126)),"Refunded Booking",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Automatic Cancellation",AS126)),"Automatic Cancellation",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Nagios Booking",AS126)),"Nagios Booking",IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Theatre",AO126)),(ISBLANK(A126))),"No Venue Ref - Theatre",IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Event",AO126)),ISBLANK(A126)),"No Venue Ref - Event", IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Event",AO126)),VLOOKUP(A126,Confirmed,40,FALSE),FALSE))))))),"Didn't Rebook")
```

This formula checks the cells previous to it on the same row to check if the last check performed was able to identify the order attribute.

[image: The current checking method.]
As Brief background to the check I need to do

- Automatic Cancellation --> Checks whether a cell's text is "AUTO"
- Refunded Booking --> Checks whether a cell's value is above 1 AND cell on same row
- Nagios Booking --> Checks whether a cell's value in column B (same row) is 0
- Zero Ticket Booking --> Checks whether a cell's value in column U (same row) is 0

A final check that hasn't been setup yet is my most troublesome. I want to check the date an order was confirmed against the date it was cancelled (which is possible). It is possible that there is no cancelled date or that there is only a cancelled date.

Because of the fact there is potential for there to be no confirmed/cancelled booking with the same Venue Reference(UNIQUE ID), I have attempted this but not been able.

```
=IF(OR(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Confirmed,33,FALSE)=0,0),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Cancelled,33,FALSE)=0,0)),1,2)
```

Or this

```
=IF(AND(VLOOKUP(A4,Confirmed,33,FALSE)>0,(VLOOKUP(A4,Cancelled,33,FALSE)> 0)),VLOOKUP(A4,Confirmed,33,FALSE)>VLOOKUP(A4,Cancelled,33,FALSE), IF(AND(VLOOKUP(A4,Confirmed,33,FALSE)<1,(VLOOKUP(A4,Cancelled,33,FALSE)> 0)),"NOT CONF/ YES CANC", IF(AND(VLOOKUP(A4,Confirmed,33,FALSE)>0,(VLOOKUP(A4,Cancelled,33,FALSE)>1)),"YES CONF/NO CANC",2)))
```

Let me know what detail is required for a better understanding of my answer. For instance the last formula has a vlookup and column_index(33) is the date.

Edit: My lists now consist of:
[image: My Name Manager]
[image: The sheets in my workbook.]

- The Confirmed is a list of confirmed bookings in a separate sheet.
- The Cancelled is a list of cancelled bookings in a separate sheet.
- The Theatre is a list of theatre/events in a separate sheet to
  evaluate whether the booking is for an event or theatre.
- The Statuses list is newly created in response to Variatus' answer.

Comment: You have added the `vba` tag to your post but I see no mention of VBA at all. Are you wanting to create some VBA code to run these checks? If so, you should provide your code so we can assist further with it.

Comment: Hi Dean, I'm not sure if the solution will involve VBA, leaving that open as an option so that people that know it would be vrey possible in VBA to take a look. I have attempted in VBA but have been unsuccessful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula is unpenetratable. For one thing, we don't know where your named range "Confirmed" is located, for another `SEARCH("Event",AO126)` will return a number whether AO126 holds "No Value Ref - Event" or just "Event", not finally, your formula returns a useful result only if it throws and error and, finally, it's evaluating results of results instead of drinking straight from the mother's breast.

With that said, I would create a named range, preferably in a separate sheet dedicated to lists and hidden from sight (and interference), with the values "Zero Ticket booking", "Refund Booking", "Automatic Cancellation" and "Nagios Booking" in it. I will refer to this range by the name of *Statuses* here. Use this range to feed validation dropdowns from which to select cell contents in AP:AS or refer to it in formulas, like `=IF(B126=0, Index(Statuses,4),""`. The immediate effect of introducing this range will be to enable you to replace all SEARCH functions in your formula with equality tests, like `IF(AS126=INDEX(Statuses,1),True,False)`

Next up, your formula evaluates two conditions only, that is if AS126 is blank or not. Please work this logic into your formula's base: `=IF(AS126="","Do one thing","Do the other")`. That will dispose of all your `AND` conditions.

If AS126 isn't blank, this formula should work. `INDEX(Statuses,(MATCH(AS126,Statuses,0)))`. MATCH just finds the row number in *Statuses* where the matching string is.

What to do if AS126 is blank is a secret you haven't disclosed, as explained above. Try and tackle the problem by the same method, however. Assign the possible values to a named range, use that range to fill cells in your worksheet and then use the result of MATCH to return a value from another range (instead of the same, as I have done above).

Assume you have "Zero Ticket Booking" in AO126. Therefore `MATCH(AO126,Statuses,0)` will return 1. Assume you have a named range "Output" with "A,B,C,D" in it. `INDEX(Output, 1)` would therefore return "A". Therefore `INDEX(Output, MATCH(AO126,Statuses,0))` would also return "A". You can use this to simplify your formula.

Comment: I've setup an Index check formula in column AW, 
`=IF(AH2="AUTO",INDEX(Statuses,3),IF(B2=0,INDEX(Statuses,4),IF(AND(AN2="Cancelled",AI2>1),INDEX(Statuses,2),IF(U2=0,INDEX(Statuses,1),"Valid Data"))))`

Comment: I now need to add more statuses to deliberate further the status of each booking. Those without a status will be the data I can use.

Comment: The purpose of using *Statuses* is to ensure that there are no typos to upset your evaluations. Toward that end you should try to eliminate text in your formulas, to wit, "AUTO", "Cancelled". "Valid Data" might be permissible because it's written by the formula but it might be expected to be there by the next formula and then it becomes messy. You have too many columns with too much insignificant information. If it's the remainder without classification that you are after, try to go for it directly.

Comment: The INDEX function really helped here, thank you Variatus, sorry for not confirming earlier.